# Using typescript module for importing javascript library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm rather new to typescript and I'm trying to figure out how to use typescript modules.
When importing a javascript library (that I've created) I getting errors that I need to use a module in order to use this library.

Do I need to define a module for every public class / file in that library in order to use it?

Here's an example:

```
export default () => {

    const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState(false);
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const isFinished = progress === 100 && !isUploading;

    const upload = async (file) => {

        try {
            setIsUploading(true);
            console.log("useTus: upload", file);
            setProgress(0);
            const filename = await TusClient.upload(file, ({progress}) => {
                console.log("useTus: progress", progress);
                setProgress(progress);
            });
            setProgress(100);
            console.log("useTus: file upload SUCCESS", filename)
            setIsUploading(false);
            return filename;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("useTus: error", err)
            setError(err)
        }

    }

    return {isUploading, setIsUploading, upload, progress, error, isFinished}
}
```

How can I define a module for this code and how do I use the module in my typescript code?

Comment: You cannot import an ESM module in a file that is not itself an ESM module. You can either pre-compile your library into something else, or you can make the code importing the library a module. "Do I need to define a module for every public class / file in that library in order to use it?" that is not a meaningful statement, you will need to set `type: module` in the package.json.